# How to define that a variable can only be a key attribute in an array

Tags: typescript

How to dynamically obtain the type of key attribute in an array

```
const arr = [
  { key: 'a' },
  { key: 'b' },
  { key: 'c' },
];

type key = ??? // key is 'a' or 'b' or 'c'
```

Answer (score 2):

Type the array `as const` so the strings don't get widened, and then you can use `[number]` on the array type to get a union of the objects, and then `['key']` on that to get a union of the strings.

```
const arr = [
  { key: 'a' },
  { key: 'b' },
  { key: 'c' },
] as const;

type key = typeof arr[number]['key'];
```